# Detect LatLng when click on circle of googleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to detect the coordinates when the user clicks on the circle in google Maps.

I tried to first detect the click on the map and then the circle. It gives me the coordinates when I click on the circle, but first I have to click on the map and then on the circle. I would like it to be directly

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {

        if(circle.isClickable()){
            googleMap.setOnCircleClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener()     {
                @Override
                public void onCircleClick(@NonNull Circle circle) {
                    double latitude= latLng.latitude;
                    double longitude= latLng.longitude;

                    Intent ns=getCiudadPais(latitude,longitude);

                    startActivity(ns);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```